# Implicit differentiation to find derivatives of a function whose only defined by its derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

A question I have asks if $K(x)$ satisfies $K(1)=0$ and $K'(x)={1\over{x}}$ then show:

If $f(x)=K(10x)$ then $f'(x)={1\over{x}}$

So Im not sure if I have to prove it or do something else but this is what I did.
$$
f'(x)=K(10x)^0\cdot K'(10x) \cdot 10
\\
f'(x)={1\over{10x}}\cdot 10={1\over{x}}
$$
The other questions are similar to this so if this is okay then im sure I did the rest okay as well. Then it asks:
$$
Let \ g(x)=K(x^2+1)\ \ \ \ find \ g'(x)
$$
So I do:
$$
g'(x)=K'(x^2+1)\cdot 2x = {2x\over{x^2+1}}
$$
At this point I havent used the $K(1)=0$ so im not sure if im doing this right. The last sub question asks: 
If $a,b >0$ show $K(ab) = K(a)+K(b)$. Which I have no idea where to start.


Any feedback appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are doing great! For the last problem (which is quite cute) you probably already know what the function $K(x)$ is but that would spoil the fun.  Instead just use what is given.  Define $F(x)= K(ax) - K(x)$.  Check that $F'(x)$ is always zero and that $F(1) = K(a)$.  Etc.

Comment: Thank you, im interested in how you know to start with $F(x)=K(ax)-K(x)$. Also, I can see that $F'(x)$ will always be zero but I don't understand how $F(1)=K(a)=0$. I'm having trouble understanding how this shows that $K(ab) = K(a)+K(b)$.

Comment: A function with a zero derivative is constant.  What is the value of that constant then?  And $F(1)=K(a)$ (not = zero).  Why did it occur to me to define $F$ this way? Well I needed a way to exploit the fact that the derivative of $K(ax)$ and $K(x)$ were the same (as you proved).

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations seems to be totally fine in my opinion.

Note that instead of using implicit differentiation, it is possible to solve the differential equation

$$
K'(x) = \frac{1}{x},\qquad K(1)=0,
$$
and use the explicit form of $K$ in your calculations. But your method is more time efficient and does the job perfectly fine. Although the last task is easier to solve with an explicit expression of $K$, so here we go;

$$
\frac{dK}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad K(x) = \int \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln x + \alpha, \qquad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace,
$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is some constant. We know that $K(1) = 0$, i.e.
$$
k(1) = \underbrace{\ln 1}_{=0} + \alpha \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \alpha \equiv 0.
$$
Thus, it must hold that
$$
K(x) = \ln x,\qquad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace.
$$

For this reason, the proof becomes pretty straightforward;
$$
K(ab) = \ln ab = \ln a + \ln b = K(a) + K(b).
$$

Sorry for the previous answer, sleep deprivation is a bad thing... =D

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I guess its a exercise in implicit differentiation hence why im doing it this way. Implicit differentiation is pretty tough for me to wrap my mind around so I guess its probably good I do it this way. $K(x)$ isn't defined explicitly only through its derivative, in your answer I think you may have confused the derivative definition for the function definition. Thanks for your input.

Comment: The "point" of the problem (if you can say that problems have a point) is that the properties of the natural logarithm function can be deduced directly from the differential equation itself.  It is presented at a calculus level in this way in order to illustrate this "point."  Your solution is, of course, perfectly valid but much less fun.