# Implicit differentiation to find property of a function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Im asked to show that if $h(1)=0$ and $h'(x)={1\over{x}}$ then $a,b>0$ show $h(ab)=h(a)+h(b)$. Im expected to use implicit differentiation to show this property.

Comment: One of your classmates (perhaps) has already asked this question.  Try seeing if that helps you too:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552432/implicit-differentiation-to-find-derivatives-of-a-function-whose-only-defined-by

Comment: After looking at it I still have no clue. I do see that $F(1)=h(a)$ and $F'(x)=0$. But Im not sure how to use this information to show this property.

Comment: Note that $F'(x)=0$ for every $x$.  That means that this function is a constant.  What constant?  I'm sure you can see what constant.  Then this function contains all the information that you need in order to prove that $h(ab)=h(a)+h(b)$.  (Just a tiny puzzle really.)

Comment: the constant is $F(1)=h(a)$

Comment: And for observers that are too lazy to follow the link the hint for the problem that should work for all is "*Consider the function $F(x)=h(ax)-h(x)$*."

Comment: Good.  You have the constant now solve the tiny puzzle or give it to a friend who knows no calculus since that just confuses the matter.

Comment: Im getting nowhere, I don't see how it's so simple. Is there another hint you can give me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32331/discussion-between-b-s-thomson-and-user3258845).

Answer (score -1):

The question in its current form isn't correct. If we define $h(x)=\ln(x)+7$, then $h'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, but 
$$h(ab)=\ln(ab)+7,$$
$$h(a)+h(b)=\ln(a)+7+\ln(b)+7=\ln(ab)+14.$$

EDIT: With the extra information you have given, the solution follows readily from the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$f(x)=f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^xf'(y)dy,$$
where in this case we set $x_0=1$. I can't however think of any way to do this using only 'implicit differentiation'.

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot some given information. I can't use $ln(x)$ only implicit differentiation.

Answer (score -1):

Differentiate left hand side
$$dh(ab)=\frac{\partial h}{\partial a}b\ da+\frac{\partial h}{\partial b}a\ db=\frac{1}{a\ b}b\ da+\frac{1}{a\ b}a\ db=\frac{1}{a} da+\frac{1}{b} db$$
Differentiate right hand side
$$dh(a)+dh(b)=\frac{\partial h}{\partial a} da+\frac{\partial h}{\partial b} db=\frac{1}{a} da+\frac{1}{b} db$$
Both are equal

Comment: ... and therefore?

Comment: @B.S.Thomson and this is what was asked?

Comment: Not quite.  You haven't yet used all of the hypotheses of the problem.  So don't stop here.